# FuncA was not declared in this scope C programming Error

Tags: c

I'm only new in C Programming and I'm trying to learn the language. but when I compile the code I made it show an error `"FuncA was not declared in this scope"`. but I already try to declared the function below.

```
 #include<stdio.h>

 int main(){     
   int A = 1;   
   FuncA(A);   
   printf("%d\n");     
 }

 int FuncA(int B){  
    B++;        
    return B++;
 }
```

sorry for this question.

Comment: `return B++` where `B` is passed by value is weird

Comment: Using `printf("%d\n");` is undefined behaviour; you should pass an `int` value to be printed.  Ignoring the result returned by `FuncA` defeats the purpose of calling `FuncA`.  Maybe you had `A = FuncA(A);` in mind, or maybe you wanted `printf("%d\n", FuncA(A));`.  The post-increment on the return in `FuncA` is a pointless side-effect.  The compiler might even warn about these issues with appropriate warnings enabled.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put its declaration:

```
int FuncA(int B);
```

before `main()`.

Alternatively, you can move `main()` after the function definition.

---

**P.S.**: As @JonathanLeffler commented, `printf("%d\n")` is [**undefined behavior**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf):

> If any argument is not the type expected by the corresponding conversion specifier, or **if there are less arguments than required by format, the behavior is undefined**. If there are more arguments than required by format, the extraneous arguments are evaluated and ignored.

You probably want this:

```
printf("%d\n", FuncA(A));
```

Comment: Or move the function above `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

At the point when `FuncA` is called, it is not yet known by the compiler.

Move the function as shown:

```
 int FuncA(int B){  
      B++;      
      return B++;
 }

 int main(){

   int A = 1;   
   A = FuncA(A);   
   printf("%d\n", A);
 }
```

Also note that you specify in `printf` to print an integer `%d`, but you dont pass one. My code above has this fixed.

Also you probably wanted to do something with the return value of `FuncA`, I assigned it to A.

Comment: Or put a declaration of the function before `main()`.

Comment: Note that the `printf()` is bogus - in the original and your answer.

Answer (score 0):

just declare a function prototype in the global declaration:

int FuncA();