# The program won't print 'sayHi()' function

Tags: c

I'm getting this error that 'sayHi' was not declared in this scope. I don't understand why It's not working especially when I'm copying the code from C tutorial.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    sayHi();
    return 0;
}

void sayHi()
{
    printf("You made it ha");
    
}
```

Comment: Read your compiler warnings

Comment: Don't forget to accept (up-vote) one of the answers (the most helpful).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FuncA was not declared in this scope C programming Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23018561/funca-was-not-declared-in-this-scope-c-programming-error)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to call a function (or use *any* item, really), it has to be declared *before* the point where you use it. That means either introducing a prototype beforehand (declare, but define later):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sayHi(void);

int main(void) {
    sayHi();
    return 0;
}

void sayHi(void) {
    printf("You made it ha");
}
```

or re-arranging the order (declare and define together):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sayHi(void) {
    printf("You made it ha");
}

int main(void) {
    sayHi();
    return 0;
}
```

Both of those will have `sayHi()` in scope before `main()` tries to call it.

> As an aside, you'll notice I've also added in the `void` parameter list to all those functions - this is the "correct" thing to do in C since an empty parameter list is different to a forced-no-parameter list).

Comment: Thanks that fixed my problem.Now I can do my assignment!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to *declare* your function prior to using it, or you need to *define* it. Simply shuffling `sayHi()` before `main()` solves your problem, as does including the function signature.

C will presume your function takes `int` arguments returns `int` unless otherwise specified. That's not the case here.

Imagine the compiler as working linearly through your code, top to bottom, and it can only take into account things that have already been defined linearly. It does not look at the whole file before beginning to compile.

Comment: Thanks that fixed my problem. Now I can do my assignment!!!

Comment: Re "C will presume your function takes int arguments returns int unless otherwise specified.", I don't think that's correct any more - it may have been true back in the days of K&R but I think you need a return type, and a missing argument list means unspecified parameters rather the default-to-one-int.

Comment: @paxdiablo I couldn't find a citation for it in the C99 spec, but a few days ago someone posted a question with a function signature `int example(a, b, c)` which *does* compile. You do need a return type, but functions used before declaration are presumed to return `int` as per compiler warnings. With `clang` you get `implicit declaration of function 'example' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]` but it still compiles.

Comment: `gcc` won't compile with `-std=c99 -pedantic-errors` flags if the code contains an implicit function declaration.  A call to a function with no visible declaration is a *constraint violation* in C99 and beyond (it was allowed in C90). The Standard does not differentiate error and warning for compiler messages. A C99 compiler can issue a warning and then use the C90 semantics.